# How to allow html link tag in php text area

Tags: php, html

I have a php code to display text entry for user

```
<div class="entry-content">
     <p><?php echo esc_html($service['desc']);?></p>
</div>
```

i need to allow the user "my self" to enter an html link tag so i can use it inside the text area.
how to do that?

Comment: The easiest would be to simply remove the `esc_html()`, since that turns all HTML tags into entities. If that is a good solution depends on the context. Can the desc come from other sources than you? Should they be able to insert HTML?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Perfect, thanks alot

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No it's just me

Comment: Then it should be safe (if you trust yourself, that is :-))